# chef-client version 12.3.0 gives error while running knife bootstrap command in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins

I have a job in jenkins which is executing `knife bootstrap IP -x USER -P PASSWORD` which was working fine till the previous chef release i.e. 11.14.2. But when i updated chef, it started showing `Doing old-style registration with.... validator.pem` and stops execution.
Where as when i run the same command in Powershell, although it also shows the same "old-style" line, but execution of the command does succeeds.

I also tried commenting `validation_client_name` and `validation_key` in my knife.rb file. 
Now it asks me to re register the node which already exists.

I know there another way of doing it, i.e. using `knife ssh` but i still want to use knife bootstrap because when i ran `knife node run_list set` command and saw the node status, it showed run_list having my newly set cookbook, where as in recipe its still the old one. And while executing, the old cookbook is being executed

Comment: Don't understand why it fails. That is a warning. I think your problem is now compounded by the fact that the bootstrap succeeded on windows. I suggest that you first delete the "client" and "node" entry on the chef server and the contents of the "/etc/chef" directory on the node itself. Then try a fresh bootstrap. Very best of luck!

Comment: I have done that already, that too a number of times but no help.